# How to set a OutlinedTextField occupy the remaining space Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a top app bar that contains a back icon and a search. Here is what I have tried.

```
SmallTopAppBar(
    title = {
        Text(
            text = "MyApp"
        )
    },
    navigationIcon = {
        IconButton(
            onClick = navController.popBackStack()
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
    },
    actions = {
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(1f) //Here is the issue.
                .padding(2.dp)
            value = search,
            maxLines = 1,
            singleLine = true
        )
    }
)
```

The problem comes when I try to use `.fillMaxWidth(1f)`, it doesn't take only the remaining space, but it get over the arrow button?

[image]

This is what I expect:

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: How do you expect a Title and a Search Bar? Provide some sample images.

Comment: You need to use the custom topappbar. See this https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-topappbar/#custom-topappbar

Comment: @Abhimanyu I just added what I expect.

Comment: @SemicolonSpace I'm using materil3, there is no TopAppBar anymore.

Comment: Just shift your OutlinedTextField from action{} to title{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `OutlinedTextField` inside the `title` attribute instead of the `actions` attribute

```
SmallTopAppBar(
    title = {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {text = it},
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(1f) 
                .padding(2.dp),
            maxLines = 1,
            singleLine = true
        )
    },
    navigationIcon = {
        //IconButton            
    },
    actions = {
        //IconButton
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Never thought about that. It worked for me. Thank you.